# Regex for email masking - JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, npm

I need to mask email address with this types

```
// email = thisisemail@server.com
pattern = t*********l@server.com
```

I am using JavaScript.
I searched for many answers in here. All work properly in regex tester site but not working browser scripts.

Need help with w3schools.com links.

Comment: Can you post your code please? create a snippet with tools `[<>]`

Comment: [W3 Schools email validation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern4)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GTLHKP0ETIFV

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep the length of the user ID, but mask its internal characters with asterisks:

```js
function maskEmail(email) {
  const match = /([^@]+)@([^@]+)/.exec(email);
  if (match === null) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid email: ${email}`);
  }
  const user = match[1];
  const n = user.length;
  const maskedUser = n < 3 ? user : `${user[0]}${"*".repeat(n - 2)}${user[n - 1]}`;
  const server = match[2];
  return `${maskedUser}@${server}`;
}

const emails = ["a@server.com", "ab@email", "thisisemail@server.com"];
const maskedEmails = emails.map(email => maskEmail(email));
console.log(maskedEmails);
```

I think it's better not to keep the length of the userID, and only keep some characters from the beginning:

```js
function maskEmail(email) {
  const match = /([^@]+)@([^@]+)/.exec(email);
  if (match === null) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid email: ${email}`);
  }
  const user = match[1];
  const n = user.length;
  const maskedUser = `${user.substring(0, 3)}${"*".repeat(8 - Math.min(n, 3))}`;
  const server = match[2];
  return `${maskedUser}@${server}`;
}

const emails = ["a@server.com", "ab@email", "thisisemail@server.com"];
const maskedEmails = emails.map(email => maskEmail(email));
console.log(maskedEmails);
```

As you can see, this is still not ideal for 1- or 2-character user IDs (because one can easily guess those user IDs), but that can be solved e.g. by randomizing the number of characters shown (e.g. between 1 and 3).

Comment: This is not a problem not keeping exact length of user id. Normally popular email providers not supported too short user id. For example in gmail there need at least 6 character long. but, as a developer we should keep in mind all types of email. so, this will great if the user id 1/2 character long , we will not maintain the length and that will be like a*******@server.com.
but is 2 - 257 we can make the email like as
(first character)*******(last character)@server.com  a*****b@server.com
t*******l@server.co
actually I want to keep the last character though many of us make it unique.